# HTTP response header okay NOT to start with status line?

Tags: c++, rest, sockets, http

I am coding a REST API in C++, which responds to requests for files. Sometimes, the file I respond with takes a while to prepare (needs to be decrypted). The socket sometimes times out while a large file is being decrypted and my API is never able to respond with anything yet.

The requesting system will not time out when it receives some response from me.

So I was thinking of sending an initial response header (which one?), and only then do I start to decrypt. Then send the response, starting with status code, then the file, to the still-open socket.

Is this possible or is there a better way?

Comment: The usual thing would be to arrange for the file to be decrypted in such a way that you can send the start of it before the end of it is decrypted. Of course that depends on your choice of encryption. Fundamentally, if you can't send any part of the response for (say) 24 hours after the request is received, HTTP over TCP/IP is not the protocol for you...

Comment: @SteveJessop 24 hours? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Leon: the questioner has not stated how long it takes to prepare the response. I use 24 hours as an example which is clearly so long that HTTP (alone) is not appropriate. A REST API could be designed though, with a call to request that particular data is prepared (perhaps this could return an estimate of how long it will take), then another call to poll whether it's ready yet and/or collect the results once it is.

Comment: @Steve We can't respond with part of the decrypted file because that means our response should start with 200, which may not be true if decryption (for the rest of the file) cannot finish/fails, right?

Answer (score 1):

[WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518) (which is an extension to the HTTP/1.1 protocol) has introduced a [special response code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-10.1) for this case:

> #### 10.1 102 Processing
>
> The 102 (Processing) status code is an interim response used to
> inform the client that the server has accepted the complete request,
> but has not yet completed it.  This status code SHOULD only be sent
> when the server has a reasonable expectation that the request will
> take significant time to complete. As guidance, if a method is taking
> longer than 20 seconds (a reasonable, but arbitrary value) to process
> the server SHOULD return a 102 (Processing) response. The server MUST
> send a final response after the request has been completed.
>
> Methods can potentially take a long period of time to process,
> especially methods that support the Depth header.  In such cases the
> client may time-out the connection while waiting for a response.  To
> prevent this the server may return a 102 (Processing) status code to
> indicate to the client that the server is still processing the
> method.

Comment: Seems like this is what I am looking for. But how can this be done, since this seems like 2 responses? We don't own the client so I can't modify it to create another request if the first one was 102.

Comment: You don't have to wait for another request. If the client understands this response code, then it will wait for your follow-up final response.

Comment: You mean it's the same response stream sending 2 status codes?

Comment: Yes. The server may even send this status code several times in a row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`

Spec here:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.1.1

Comment: The "100 Continue" is used only when uploading a large request.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's not what the documentation says.

Comment: See section 8.2.3 of RFC 2616. 100 continue "is to allow a client that is sending a request message with a request body to determine if the origin server is willing to accept the request". That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "There is an exception to this rule: for
        compatibility with RFC 2068, a server MAY send a 100 (Continue)
        status in response to an HTTP/1.1 PUT or POST request that does
        not include an Expect request-header field with the "100-
        continue" expectation."

Comment: Note "PUT or POST request", not GET request. 100 is an encouragement to the user agent to continue uploading the body of the request. I suspect (but don't know for sure) that once the body of the request is uploaded browsers will ignore it, so it's possible that it will serve to keep the socket from timing out. It might not keep the browser from timing out.

Comment: @SteveJessop the OP does not specify the type of request he's dealing with so fair enough. I guess I saw "need to decrypt" and thought, well, the decryption key is going to have to get there somehow... A wise REST interface architect would not make it part of the query string...

Comment: @RichardHodges: sure. If the client has the key then making a REST call to decrypt it seems weird: I imagined some "at rest" encryption being removed. But good point, we can as well assume the key comes with the request as assuming anything else. If this is a POST request then the questioner can at least try 100 to see if it stops the browser timing out. If it works, try to figure out whether it can be expected to work :-)

Comment: 100 is fine, and independent of the request type. Also, please don't bother with RFC 2616; this part has been obsoleted by RFC 7231 two years ago.

Comment: This is a GET. And yes it's an "at rest" encryption being removed. It seems 100 is not appropriate here because I am not receiving the request anymore so I can't tell the client to "continue". The other answer, 102, seems more appropriate, but not sure how to send 2 status codes (102, then later 200) as one response. Help?

Comment: @obay literally send the string "HTTP/1.1 102 Please Wait\r\n\r\n" - that will complete the first header - then you can send your second header + body when you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

Not within the context of the `HTTP` protocol itself. There's nothing like this in the `HTTP` protocol proper.

Something like this is typically implemented at a higher level. This is typically done by the original request initiating the long-running task, in the background, and returning a temporary "Please wait..."-type of a page. The page's javascript immediately executes an AJAX call. On the server, the AJAX call waits a moderate amount of time, typically a minute, for the process to finish. If it is still running the AJAX call returns an indication accordingly, and the client-side javascript issues another call. The client-side javascript continues to make periodic AJAX call, waiting for the background process to finish.

Eventually, the AJAX call returns an indication that the background task has finished, at which time the client-side javascript executes an HTTP request to immediately retrieve the ready-to-be-retrieved document.

Comment: We do not own the client and cannot modify the code.

Comment: If you do not own the client and cannot modify the code, then you obviously can't do anything about a client making a request, and expecting a response to that request. The client will have to wait until you finish processing the request. The only remotely possible hack is a custom http server that keeps sending a dummy header "Foo: bar\r\n" to the client, every minute or so, until processing is ready, then sending the real header.